# Why my socket.io event fails to trigger inside the scope of my promise chains or inside the scope of a function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sockets, scope

This post is about better understand the React.component mechanism. 
When trying to emit an event from my client to my server using socket, the communication works if I emit from outside any function or in the definition space above the render, in my React's component. 
If I try to emit in a function or inside my promise's chain scope, it fails.  I'm wondering why it works or fails since I have defined the elements in action, and my console.log of theses returns me their definition.

Here my snippet.js:

```
componentDidMount(){ 
    console.log("on componentDidMount")
    this.socket=io();
    axios.get("https://api.ipify.org/?format=json")
           .then((res) => { 
       // INSIDE THE PROMISE CHAIN'S SCOPE => FAILS TO EMIT ANYTHING 
       // I CAN'T FIGURE OUT WHY => BUT IT WORKS NOW. 
       // MAYBE A RESETTING I HAVE DONE WITHOUT HAVING SPOT THE CHANGEMENT 
       this.socket.emit("join", {ip:56565454654}, function(err){   
       });
    }) 

    // INSIDE A FUNCTION SCOPE IN componentDidMount() => FAILS TO EMIT ANYTHING WHEN CALL FROM PROMISE'CHAIN
    // EDIT => WORKS => HAD TO BE BOUND
    join(ip){  
    } 

    // OUTSIDE ANY FUNCTION SCOPE INSIDE componentDidMount() => EMIT SUCCEED BUT HARD TO HANDLE THE CODE FLOW SINCE IT ISN'T CALLED
    this.socket.on("join",({message})=>{   
    })
}

 // IN DEFINIITION AERA OUTSIDE componentDidMount() => EMIT SUCCEED AND CODE FLOW FRIENDLY 
 join(ip){  
 }
```

So why it works or fails?

So basically the following code works well:

A:

```
  componentDidMount(){ 
        console.log("on componentDidMount")
        this.socket=io(); 

        axios.get("https://api.ipify.org/?format=json")
        .then((res) => {
            console.log("ip adress: ", res.data.ip ) 
            this.join(res.data.ip) 
        })  
  }
  // IN DEFINIITION AERA OUTSIDE componentDidMount() => EMIT SUCCEED AND CODE FLOW FRIENDLY 
  join(ip){ 
      console.log("this.socket.emit in join(): ", this.socket.emit)
      this.socket.emit("join", {ip}, function(err){ 
        if(err){ 
            alert(err);
            // Router.replace("/");
        } else{ 
            console.log("joinRoom succeed");
        }
      });    
  }
```

Any hint would be great,
thanks

Comment: Which error did you have when socket failed?

Comment: no error or a silent error -my program continues to run-, is just like the trigger never occurs

Comment: post the code that should works, without any commented code, please.

Comment: @samb102 I have modified my pose

Comment: The difference is your passing argument into the `join` function & socket.emit. In the `join` func, you send directly the value `res.data.ip` while in `socket.emit`, you use json object. I don't know what data type the socket server expects in this case so test the socket.emit with the same data as your join func & see if it works. Try `this.socket.emit("join", {res.data.ip}, function(err){ });` in the promise.

Comment: @Juky I have tried  ` this.socket.emit("join", {ip}, function(err){ });` it doesn't works

Comment: @Webwoman The value to be sent should be `res.data.ip` ?

Comment: @Webwoman `join(){}` isn't bind on `this`... bind it or modify it into an arrow function.

Comment: @Juky My bad, I have forgotten to precise that to be able to ss just`ip` I have made `axios.get("https://api.ipify.org/?format=json")
        .then((res) => res.data.ip).then( ip =>{ `

Comment: @Webwoman you return the value in `then` not another `promise` so that why it cannot go through the second `then` & the `socket.emit` not be executed. Just test the `socket.emit` in the first `then`, it should work.

Comment: @samb102 bound works. Now there is the last fails' case, where I call the socket event directly inside the promise's chain

Comment: @Juky okay it's works, thanks :), I can't figure out why it works now, please guyz, what would you advice me to dive in to better understand the mechanism?